# Compilation errors with M1 MacBook Pro and cmake

Tags: c++, c, xcode, macos, cmake

I have just got my new M1 MacBook Pro and am trying to compile a code base required for my university work. Here are the steps I have taken:

1. I set Terminal to always open using Rosetta.
2. Installed homebrew `using /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
3. Installed cmake using `brew install cmake`
4. Run `cmake <path to source>` (this works fine)
5. Run `make` (this fails)

Here is the error I get:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:97:15: fatal error: 
      'stdlib.h' file not found
#include_next <stdlib.h>
```

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing Xcode and CommandLineTools to no avail.

When using the cmake gui app, I get a different error. I have it set to use CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOsX11.0.sdk.

When running `make` after generating and configuring the build files using this cmake gui setup, I get this error:

```
    -- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.0.12000032
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 12.0.0.12000032
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc - broken
CMake Error at /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:66 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /Users/freyamurphy/nori/build/ext_build/src/tbb_p-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
```

If I run the command `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc test.c` (Simple hello world program) I get this error:

```
test.c:1:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include "stdio.h"
```

But using `cc test.c` everything works fine. (This runs usr/bin/cc).

Seems to me there is perhaps an issue with Xcode. Has anyone had any similar issues or could give me some advice? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: I had this kind of problem and I fixed by just removing the build dir and running Cmake again I also moved the the source dir to other directory but I dont think that is changes something

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you reopen Terminal after xcode installed? It's needed to set the environment variable `SDKROOT`.

Close and run again Terminal or open a new tab in Terminal.

Or run the following command in the current Terminal

```
export SDKROOT=$(xcrun --sdk macosx --show-sdk-path)
```

Also be sure the proper xcode toolchain is selected

```
# list available xcode toolchains
xcode-select -p

# select one of listed above
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this worked! I now have some other errors, but they seem to be about something different.

Comment: For me, the key was running the export command you included. For some reason, simply opening a new tab in Terminal didn't fix anything.