# MacOS BigSur cmake "Could NOT find ZLIB"

Tags: macos, cmake, lib, macos-big-sur

I have recently updated to macOS Big Sur and am now having problems compiling a C++ code base using cmake.

I have already solved some issues related to Xcode configurations (see my question here [Compilation errors with M1 MacBook Pro and cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65276102/compilation-errors-with-m1-macbook-pro-and-cmake)).

My new problem is as follows: When I run `make` I get the following output:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.19.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:218 (message):
  Could NOT find ZLIB (missing: ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.19.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:577 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.19.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindZLIB.cmake:115 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:53 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

I have tried setting values for ZLIB_LIBRARY and ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR in cmake gui but it still doesn't work, I guess I set them to the wrong thing. Where exactly should I find zlib on macOS Big Sur and what files do ZLIB_LIBRARY and ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR need to point to?

Comment: the traditional locus is `/usr/lib/libz.dylib`

Comment: @RichardBarber I don't have a libz.dylib file in my /usr/lib.

Comment: As you are already using homebrew, try to install zlib via `brew install zlib`.

Comment: @vre I have tried that and set ZLIB_LIBRARY and ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR to /usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11/lib and /usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11/include but it hasn't made a difference.

Comment: Did you deleted your CMakeCache.txt or the entire build directory after making those changes? Sometimes this is necessary. Simply installing it with homebrew and not setting those variables should be sufficient.

Comment: @vre Yup, I've deleted the whole build directory before trying again. When installing via homebrew I get a message that zlib is not symlinked into usr/local, then a message about setting LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS which I have also done.

Comment: Is that a public repository you're trying to build? If yes, add that information to the question body.

Comment: @vre Unfortunately no, it's a private repo supplied by my university. I was able to build it without any issues on Catalina though.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas, as my knowledge is based mostly on Catalina and Mojave.

Comment: @vre No problem, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I eventually managed to fix this by modifying my CMakeConfig.txt file. There was a line

```
execute_process(COMMAND bash -c "xcodebuild -version -sdk | grep MacOSX | grep \"MacOSX10.1\\d.sdk\" | grep Path | head -n 1 | cut -f 2 -d ' '" OUTPUT_VARIABLE CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT)
```

which I replaced with

```
execute_process(COMMAND xcrun --show-sdk-path OUTPUT_VARIABLE CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT)
```

Not sure why the MacOS sdk version would make a difference with ZLIB, but this fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the function of usr/lib/ has been changed in MacOS Big Sur. See eskimo's post here - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/655588 for the backstory and where the libraries have been moved to.